# Missing Calculator icon in Ubuntu 18.04 with vanilla GNOME

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, gnome-calculator

I have installed vanilla GNOME shell in Ubuntu 18.04 and the icon of Calculator is missing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install the `gnome-calculator` package?

Comment: No, I kept the original app.

Answer (score 10):

The pre-installed (GNOME) Calculator application on Ubuntu 18.04 is a [snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro) application, it doesn't have `.desktop` launcher(s) for the application at traditional place(s), e.g. `/usr/share/applications/`. Check the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory instead.

Alternatively, you may consider creating a custom `.desktop` launcher for the application by hand. To do so, follow the steps below.

1. Create a new file, say `calculator.desktop` in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do that by running the following in Terminal

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/calculator.desktop
   ```
2. Open this file with a text-editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/calculator.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following lines to this file and save the file.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Calculator
   Comment=Perform arithmetic, scientific or financial calculations
   Exec=/snap/bin/gnome-calculator
   Type=Application
   Icon=accessories-calculator
   Terminal=false
   NoDisplay=false
   ```

---

You may also remove the snap version by running

```
snap remove gnome-calculator
```

and install the traditional apt versions by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```